# Wrapping common mocked functions in gmock/gtest

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

In my gtest framework, I mocked a few functions and written some testcases. And I see that I used the same mock functions over and over with EXPECT_CALL in many testcases. So, I am just wondering if I can place these common mock EXPECT_CALL's in one place and simply call them, so the number of lines become less and the testcase looks simpler.

I tried putting them in one function and tried to call the function but it gave me many compile issues. Any one has any idea?

Comment: can you provide some code example and the list of errors?

Comment: Most likely you will need to create custom MACROs which define your commonly used mocks.

Answer (score 0):

From Google [Mock doc relative to GTest](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies#Using_Mocks_in_Tests), it is not possible to delegate to a function the  EXPECT_CALL macro.

More precisely,

> Important note: Google Mock requires expectations to be set before the
>   mock functions are called, otherwise the behavior is undefined. In
>   particular, you mustn't interleave EXPECT_CALL()s and calls to the
>   mock functions.

Comment: This answer is contains correct information, but is irrelevant to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

The `EXPECT` calls need to be inside a test case or a test fixture. You can achieve the result you want using a test fixture.

```
class MyTest : public ::testing::test
{
    MyTest // can use ctor
    {
        EXPECT_CALL(mock, ...);
    }

    SetupA()  // or can use a member function
    {
        EXPECT_CALL(mock, ...);
        EXPECT_CALL(mock, ...);

    }

    MockObject mock;
};

TEST_F(MyTest, TestOne)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, ...);
    // do something - two expectations are set
}

TEST_F(MyTest, TestTwo)
{
    SetupA();
    // do something - three expectations are set
}
```